# How do you create a dropdown menu to sort calendar events in drupal calendar module?

Tags: drupal, drop-down-menu, calendar

How do you create a dropdown menu to sort calendar events in drupal calendar module?

I know many people are struggling with this same issue.  Can anyone help???

Thanks in advance!

---

Thanks for the response.  This is basically what I am planning on doing but I have many types of events.  Do know if there is a way to create a drop down menu of links that will appear withing a block?  It would be great to have two drop downs.  One to select type of event and one to select a date range.

Is anyone aware of a module or an outside service that has type calendar with these features already available?  I have looked at Trumba and it looks really nice but the price tag is way too hefty.  $100 a month is crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Create an different view for each filter permutation of interest. Add them as tabs to a single page, or as separate pages and add links to each in the header or as a separate block.

To sort by date ascending, load one view; to sort descending, load another.

Answer (score 0):

making the links into a drop down menu is just CSS. look at the suckerfish menu code, it's pretty straightforward. Alternatively you could use the nice menus module and place a block containing the items of choice above the calendar.